# Allow excerpt in JSON RestKit

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

If I have a JSON view that looks like this for a user object in my API:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "posts": [
        { "id": 102 },
        { "id": 101 },
        { "id": 100 }
    ]
}
```

There are never more than three items in the posts array, it is supposed to represent the three most recent. However, if more posts, like `{ "id": 99 }` have already been downloaded, RestKit will assume that they no longer exist and that only the three posts in the array on the user view are still around.

**How can I make RestKit merge the newly-loaded posts with the currently loaded posts, rather than just deleting older ones to make room for the new?**

I'm also open to changing my JSON if there's a better way to do this.

These are my mappings:

```
RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"avatar_url": @"avatarURL",
    @"id":         @"userID",
    @"first_name": @"firstName",
    @"last_name":  @"lastName",
    @"username":   @"username",
    @"followed":   @"followed"
}];
userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"userID"];

RKEntityMapping *postMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[postMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id":          @"postID",
    @"content_url": @"contentURL",
    @"created_at":  @"createdAt"
}];
postMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"postID"];

[userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"posts"    toKeyPath:@"posts"   withMapping:postMapping]];
[postMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"creator"  toKeyPath:@"creator" withMapping:userMapping]];

[postMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"replies"  toKeyPath:@"replies" withMapping:postMapping]];
[postMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"reply_to" toKeyPath:@"replyTo" withMapping:postMapping]];
```

Comment: Why make RestKit do it if Core Data would be more than happy to do it if you updated the MOC with the new data?

Comment: @CodaFi one of the purposes of RestKit is to handle this for me, is it not? I didn't even know I could do it myself.

Comment: RestKit has a fairly liberal merge policy, if memory serves, so you're right to assume there's little you can do Core-Data-wise.  You may have to just forgo RK and write an NSOperation to do [manual merging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html).

Comment: How have you configured you're mapping, and your object identities? You usually have to request RestKit to purge old data and tell it how to find that old data.

Comment: @Wain I've added the mappings. Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to build the relationship mapping:

```
RKRelationshipMapping *postRelationMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"posts" toKeyPath:@"posts" withMapping:postMapping]
postRelationMapping.assignmentPolicy = RKUnionAssignmentPolicy;

[userMapping addPropertyMapping:postRelationMapping];
```